# Kotlin: How to convert from binary to decimal

Tags: kotlin

I need to convert from Binary String to Int or Long in Kotlin. Is there any inbuilt utility method available for the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

that's how you can do;

```
println("11001".toInt(2))
println("11001".toLong(2))
```

As Joffrey said in the comment, "the 2 here is the number's base. That's why it's 2 for binary, would be 16 for hexadecimal"

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the 2 here is the number's base. That's why it's 2 for binary, would be 16 for hexadecimal etc.

Comment: Inverse operation: `Integer.toBinaryString(25)` => `"11001"`